# 'php artisan migrate' remains suspended and does not cause errors

Tags: php, laravel

I started a new project using `laravel^6.2` using the `laravel new myapp` command.

I edit then my `.env` file to connect to my local database:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=8082
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

I decide then to `migrate` the default database structure from laravel. when I say default structure I'm talking about the `users` migration which is already created from the beginning present in the `2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php` file:

```php
<?php

// *** This has been generated from `laravel new myapp` ***

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

So I run the `php artisan migrate` command and then something unexpected happens. Indeed, after that the terminal doesn't do anything as if it was on break. I'm thinking maybe the command takes a while to execute but after several tries that lasted about ten minutes, nothing happens.

So I decide to consult the logs but absolutely nothing's written down, it's totally empty.

So I'm trying to execute `php artisan cache:clear` and start over but the result is the same: No error messages and nothing happens.

I know the question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30393587/why-does-php-artisan-migrate-nothing) before, but no answer really came up.

Has somebody an idea what I have missed ?

Comment: Port 8082 is an unusual port for MySQL, it's usually 3306, have you set that port on your MySQL server?

Comment: What's your os and how you're hosting your MySQL? if you're using xampp, xampp is using 3306 port for mysql since it's default port after all. share your mysql informations.

Comment: @kerbholz Well my localhost server run on port `8082` but this obviously has nothing to do with the MySql port. With port `3306` it's work well thanks. I'm still surprised that laravel's cli doesn't handle this error message. I'll be happy to validate your answer if you feel like writing it.

Comment: Glad it works.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the port to the default MySQL port `3306`.

Port `8082` as you have it sounds unusual, unless you have set that port in your MySQL server.

From your comment: 
there are multiple "localhost" servers running on your machine:

- your localhost *web* server, port 80 usually (in your case 8082)
- your localhost *mysql* server, port 3306 usually.

There might also be a localhost *postgres* server, running (default) at port `5432`, a localhost *redis* server at port `6379` or many others.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)